# Subclasses instantiating superclass of class Human

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a test which looks like this:

- Create a base class `Human`
- `Human class` needs to have a method `Talk`
- The `Human` class needs to have to descendant class `Man` and `Woman`
- Both `Man` and `Woman` should have their own `Talk` method (basically rewrite the method)
- The `Man` class should have a `private` property `_foo`
- It should have a method `getInfo` (which needs to be an Ajax call and log the response)
- I need to make 1000 instances of the `Women` class in the `window` namespace (I mean global)
- On `document.body` single click, a random `Woman` should call the `Talk` method
- On `document.body` double click, the `Man`'s `getInfo` method should be called

```
function Human(){};

Human.prototype.talk = function(){
    console.log('Make an Human sound');
}

function Woman(){
    Human.call(this);
}


Woman.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Woman.prototype.constructor = Woman;

Woman.prototype.talk = function(){
    console.log('Miau');
}

function Man(){
    var foo = 10;
    Human.call(this);
}


Man.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Man.prototype.constructor = Man;

Man.prototype.talk = function(){
    console.log('Wuff');
}

Man.prototype.getInfo = function(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {           
        console.log('Ajax response: ' + xhr.readyState);            
    };
}

var woman = new Woman();

console.log('woman instance of Woman ' + (woman instanceof Woman));
console.log('woman instance of Human ' + (woman instanceof Human));

woman.talk();

var man = new Man();

console.log('man instance of Man ' + (man instanceof Man));
console.log('man instance of Human ' + (man instanceof Human));

man.talk();

womans = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    womans[i] = new Woman();        
}

document.body.onclick = function(){     
    var randNr = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
    womans[randNr].talk();
    console.log('Random Woman: ' + randNr);
 }
 document.body.ondblclick = function(){
          Man.prototype.getInfo();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some opinions:

> ```
> function Woman(){
>     Human.call(this);
> }
> Woman.prototype = new Human();
> ```

[Don't use `new` for prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) (even when it doesn't matter here as long as `Human` is empty, but the `Huma.call(this)` suggests otherwise). Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898786/1048572

> ```
> // Woman subClass
> function Man(){
> ```

Apparently not.

> ```
>     var _foo = 10;
> ```

It's a local-scoped ("private") variable anyway, you don't need to prefix it with an underscore. Notice that it is only accessible from functions declared within the constructor, of which you don't have any.

> ```
>     return Human.call(this);
> ```

No reason to `return` anything here. It might even be wrong it `Human` did return an object.

> ```
> Man.prototype.getInfo = function(method, url){
>     […]
> }
> ```

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with instances of `Man`, so I wonder why it is a method? But that's probably just the design of your test case.

> ```
> console.log('man private variable _foo: ' + (man._foo));
> ```

Not sure what you did expect, but yes, since `_foo` has been a variable and not a property of the object so this is `undefined`.

> ```
> document.body.onclick = function(){     
>     […]
> ```

…is missing a closing brace.

> ```
> var randNr = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
> womans[randNr].talk();
> ```

No. That `randNr` will be in the range 1-1000 (both inclusive), while your array indices are 0-999. With a small chance, this will throw an exception. Remove the `+1`.

> ```
> console.log('Random Woman: ' + randNr);
> ```

…and add it here if you want that output one-based.

> ```
> Man.prototype.getInfo();
> ```

That confirms what I said above - you don't use an instance for that method. You should hardly ever call methods on the prototype object - `man.getInfo()` would be better. But if you really intended this to be a static function, you might write `Man.getInfo = function() {…};` and then call `Man.getInfo();`.

Comment: I edited the code, please could you take a second and check if now the code is suffice for the test above. i would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Uh, actually I had only looked at the code since you can check whether it meets your expectatations by simply executing it :-) I'd say it does what is described, the only term that striked me was "*private property*" as such by definition don't exist :-)